# How do I change the "run project" toolbar to default in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-toolbar

My mouse suddenly went crazy and moved the "run project" toolbar in Android Studio, I tried searching in Google but I can't find any answer. I tried "Restore Default Layout" in Windows tab but it is not restoring it. The screenshot is right [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NARs.png).

[image]

Comment: if restore does not work reopen studio should fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In menu : View - check "Toolbar"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Right click  on toolbar then you can customize the menus and toolbars options

[image]

2) Then select restore default and click ok

[image]